# XmlSerializer putting element name inside a property when deserializing

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an issue with the .NET XML Serializer where I have do different XML Elements with different names that map to the same type. Basically, the objects should be exactly the same, but I want them to have a string or enum or something that identifies which of the three possible element names were used. So here's an example:

```
<Body>
  <MyTypeA>
    <Foo>bar</Foo>
  </MyTypeA>
  <MyTypeB>
    <Foo>bar</Foo>
  </MyTypeB>
</Body>
```

Now, for the classes, `MyTypeA` and `MyTypeB` will both be the same type. For example:

```
public class Body {
  public MyType MyTypeA { get; set; }
  public MyType MyTypeB { get; set; }
}

public class MyType {
  public string Foo { get; set; }

  [XmlIgnore]
  public MyTypeType { get; set; }
}

public enum MyTypeType
{
  MyTypeA,
  MyTypeB
}
```

When serializing it works fine, because I can always just ensure one way or another that the enum is set properly before serializing. But when deserializing it is not getting set and I'm not sure there's a way how.

For the record, I unfortunately don't get to set the schema, otherwise I would have built it in such a way that I didn't have this problem.

Comment: Do you want to have different default enum values in the MyType objects referred to by the MyTypeA and MyTypeB properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, this might help you. Just write you XML file path on the 4th line and try it.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

class Program
{
    //private const string xmlPath = @"C:\Users\Jumast\Desktop\StackOverflowQuestion.xml";
    private const string xmlPath, // put the file path here

    static Body makeBody()
    {
        var instance1 = new MyType() { Category = Category.MyTypeA, Foo = "bar" };
        var instance2 = new MyType() { Category = Category.MyTypeB, Foo = "bar" };
        return new Body(){Instance1 = instance1, Instance2 = instance2};
    }

    static void serializeBody(Body body, string path)
    {
        var ser = new DataContractSerializer(body.GetType(), body.GetType().Name, "");
        using (var w = XmlWriter.Create(path, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }))
        {
            ser.WriteObject(w, body);
        }
    }

    static Body deseerializeBody(string xmlPath)
    {
        Body deserializedBody;
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Body));
        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(xmlPath))
        {
            deserializedBody = (Body)ser.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        return deserializedBody;
    }

    static void writeBodyToConsole(Body body)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance1: " + body.Instance1);
        Console.WriteLine("Instance2: " + body.Instance2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        serializeBody(makeBody(), xmlPath);
        writeBodyToConsole(deseerializeBody(xmlPath));
    }
}

public class Body : IXmlSerializable
{
    #region Properties
    public MyType Instance1 { get; set; }
    public MyType Instance2 { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region IXmlSerializable
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        Instance1 = new MyType(reader);
        Instance2 = new MyType(reader);
        reader.ReadEndElement();

    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        Instance1.WriteXml(writer);
        Instance2.WriteXml(writer);
    }
    #endregion
}

public class MyType : IXmlSerializable
{
    #region Fields
    private Category _category;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public MyType()
    {
        _category = Category.nil;
        Foo = string.Empty;
    }
    public MyType(XmlReader reader) { ReadXml(reader);}
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(string.Format("Foo = {0}", Foo));
        sb.Append(" , ");
        sb.Append(string.Format("Category = {0}", Category));
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public Category Category
    {
        get { return this._category; }
        set { this._category = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region IXmlSerializable
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        Enum.TryParse(reader.Name, out _category);
        reader.Read();
        Foo = reader.ReadElementContentAsString("Foo", "");
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(this.Category.ToString(), "");
        writer.WriteElementString("Foo", Foo);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
    #endregion
}

public enum Category
{
    MyTypeA,
    MyTypeB,
    nil
}
}
```

Comment: This definitely puts me on the right track. The problem is that in my real case there are more sub-elements besides just `Foo`, and some of them are complex objects, or arrays of objects, all of which can be deserialized just fine with the default logic. Is there a way for me to do that without having to implement IXmlSerializable on every class above and below this one in the hierarchy?

Comment: OK, I think I've got it figured out. I can use ReadSubtree to get complex elements and ReadElementContentAsString for simple ones. I basically have to read THIS whole element in my code, but all the stuff above and below it can use the standard attributes and logic. You saved me with this! Thanks!